# PHP and shell, user acces stuff

Tags: php, bash, shell, ubuntu-14.04

I want PHP to be able to create a folder in a folder where it does not have access. The created folder should in the end be owned by the user virtual and the group virtual.

I have tried added the following to visudo.

```
virtual  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /var/mail/virtual
_www ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /var/mail/virtual
```

With that I try the following command from php with `exec();`

```
sudo -u virtual mkdir /var/mail/virtual/test.com
```

The command works when executed through a terminal, but not when called through php.

Anyone able to tell me where i went wrong?

The server is running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made it work, somehow.

Changed the visudo to

```
www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASWD: /var/mail/virtual, /var/mail/virtual/dir.sh
```

Placed the script `dir.sh` in the folder and changed the command in the PHP part to

```
sudo /var/mail/virtual/dir.sh $dir
```

Comment: Don't forget to double-quote your expansions! :-) i.e. `"$dir"`

Comment: This approach introduces a *major* vulnerability. If the `dir.sh` script is modified or replaced -- which the `www-data` user can do, because they have been given access to the directory containing it! -- they can run any command as any user on the system. Big uh-oh.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of things going wrong here.

1. Entries in `/etc/sudoers` specify commands that can be run, not directories that can be accessed.
2. There is generally no `_www` user on Ubuntu systems. That username is an artifact of Mac OS X.
3. The first user in the command line is the user that is being allowed to *invoke* sudo, not the user that they can run the command as.

A more appropriate solution here would be:

```
www-data ALL = (virtual) mkdir /var/mail/virtual/*
```

There are still some subtle vulnerabilities in this command specification (it's possible to escape `/var/mail/virtual` and create directories in other locations where `virtual` has permissions), but it's much more secure than what you've come up with.